# Prototype.js - Handling *Event.observe* and *Cancel* trigger together

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, prototypejs, blur

I am facing a peculiar problem with my `Event.observe` trigger.

Below is the problem set:

I have a text box which triggers an ajax call with

```
Event.observe(textbox,'blur',function(){ 
    /* Ajax call */
});
```

I also have a cancel button on the same page which will close that popup.

*Issue*:
Once I start typing in the text box and then if I want to cancel, Event.observe event gets triggered because of event that was scheduled for 'blur' and hence the ajax call is triggered before the event for cancel is called.

Anyone faced a similar issue? Any workaround for this? Or I am doing something wrong?
Any help or pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: How about delaying the Ajax call with `setTimeout()` for 1 or 2 seconds and if the cancel button is clicked clear the timeout before it calls the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

@Geek Num 88: Thanks for a reply, I tried the timeout thing and it worked. To get this thing to work, we changed our blur event to keypress and made it work only on tab_key, enter key etc. This made the thing to work. Thanks